Can't retrieve Array Contents (PHP)
i have the problem that it doesnt show me the matches correctly. It gives me the form-group class but shows no matches. Any ideas?
<form method="post">
<?php if (is_array($matches) && !empty($matches)): ?>
      <?php foreach ($matches as $match): ?>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label>
      <?php $match['Team1']['TeamName'] ?> vs <?php $match['Team2']['TeamName'] ?>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tips[<?= $match['MatchID'] ?>]" required>
      </label>
      </div>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
      <p>No matches found.</p>

I have the api call here:
function getMatchData($season, $matchday) {
    global $db;
    $apiUrl = "https://www.openligadb.de/api/getmatchdata/bl1/$season/$matchday";
    $matches = json_decode(file_get_contents($apiUrl), true);
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        $db->insert('matches', [
            'id' => $match['MatchID'],
            'team1' => $match['Team1']['TeamName'],
            'team2' => $match['Team2']['TeamName'],
            'team1_goals' => $match['MatchResults'][0]['PointsTeam1'],
            'team2_goals' => $match['MatchResults'][0]['PointsTeam2'],
            'season' => $season,
            'matchday' => $matchday
        ]);
    }
    return $matches;

EDIT: I found the solution myself: i've misspelled the array indexes like TeamName instead of teamName.

<?php $match['Team1']['TeamName'] ?> should be <?php echo $match['Team1']['TeamName'] ?> or <?= $match['Team1']['TeamName'] ?>

"but shows no matches" - do you mean you aren't seeing any matches, or the literal text "No matches found" is showing?

@ChrisHaas no the array is filled therefore no text is showing.

Hi @Django! If you get with the answer you can answer yourself the question and mark it as the solution.

I found the solution myself: i've misspelled the array indexes like TeamName instead of teamName.

If your matches come from the database, they don't follow the same format of the API. You then should:
#2. Don't forget the echo
<form method="post">
<?php if (is_array($matches) && !empty($matches)): ?>
      <?php foreach ($matches as $match): ?>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label>
      <?php echo $match['team1'] ?> vs <?php echo $match['team2'] ?>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tips[<? echo  $match['id'] ?>]" required>
      </label>
      </div>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
      <p>No matches found.</p>


